# POST endpoints not working with Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I am writing a daily daycare reporting app using the PERN stack and I am having issues with some of my POST endpoints. The one below works correctly:

```
  app.get('/classroomList', (req, res) => {
        classroom.getClassrooms().then((classrooms) => { res.send(classrooms) })
  })
  app.get('/classroomList/:id',(req,res)=>{
        classroom.getStudentsByClass(req.params.id).then((student)=>{
              res.send(student)
        })
  })

  app.post('/classroomList', (req, res) => {      
        classroom.createClassroom(req.body)
        .then((classroom)=>{res.send(classroom.attributes)})

              })
  app.delete('/classroomList/:id', (req, res) => {
        console.log('req received')
        classroom.deleteClassroom(req.params.id).then((classroom) => {
              res.send('Deleted')
        })
  })

}
```

However I have a few others that are written in the same exact way that come back with the error:

> TypeError students.createStudent is not a function

The one below does not work and throws the aforementioned error message

```
module.exports = (app) => {
  const students = require('../controllers/studentController')

  app.get('/studentList', (req, res) => {
        students.getStudents().then((students) => { res.send(students) })
  })

  app.delete('/studentList/:id', (req, res) => {
        students.deleteStudent(req.params.id).then((student) => {
              res.send('Deleted')
        })
  })
  app.post('/studentList', (req, res) => {  
        console.log(req.body)    
        students.createStudent(req.body)
        .then((student)=>{console.log(student.attributes)})

  })
}
```

This is the controller that works:

```
exports.createClassroom = (classroom) => {
  console.log('function accessed')
  const newClassroom = new Classroom(
        classroom)
  return newClassroom.save()
        .then(classroom => {
              return classroom;
        })
        .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
        })
```

And this one doesn't:

```
 exports.createStudent = (student) => {
              console.log('function accessed')
              const newStudent = new Student(
                    student)
              return newStudent.save()
                    .then(student => {
                          return student;
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                          console.log(err)
                    })
        }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! It's likely there's something off in your `studentController` file -- can you edit your question to include that code as well?

Comment: if I'm reading it correctly the error is pointing to the route file:

Comment: TypeError: students.createStudent is not a function
    at app.post (C:\Users\kenpe_000\Desktop\daycare_app\daycare\daycare_backend\
routes\studentRoute.js:18:22)

Comment: Everything looks fine in the code you posted (ignoring all the missing curly brackets), so the problem probably lies in the code you didn't post.